# filtering a list of lists containing tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

i have the following example:

```
tuples = [[('2018','Q1','Dept1'),('2018','Q2','Dept2')],[('2018','Q1','Dept1'),('2018','Q1','Dept2')],[('2018','Q2','Dept1'),('2018','Q2','Dept2')]]
```

so each item in tuples is a list with 2 elements, each of which is a tuple of 3 elements.

i want to produce a final list, `newlist`, which is filtered according to the first 2 values of each tuple in each list being equivalent

so, so in this example, i would expect `newlist` to look like:

```
[[('2018', 'Q1', 'Dept1'), ('2018', 'Q1', 'Dept2')],
 [('2018', 'Q2', 'Dept1'), ('2018', 'Q2', 'Dept2')]]
```

this is a simplified example, while real size of `tuples` could be much larger

Comment: do you want to remove any duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below, iterating trough `tuples`, then check if first two elements of first element of `i` is the same as the second element's:

```
>>> [i for i in tuples if i[0][:2]==i[1][:2]]
[[('2018', 'Q1', 'Dept1'), ('2018', 'Q1', 'Dept2')], [('2018', 'Q2', 'Dept1'), ('2018', 'Q2', 'Dept2')]]
>>>
```

Or course you can also use `filter`:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda i: i[0][:2]==i[1][:2]],tuples))
[[('2018', 'Q1', 'Dept1'), ('2018', 'Q1', 'Dept2')], [('2018', 'Q2', 'Dept1'), ('2018', 'Q2', 'Dept2')]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first make a dictionary based on the first two elements:

```
entries = {}
for tuple in tuples:
    key = tuple[:2]
    entries[key] = entries.get(key, []) + [tuple[2]]
```

Then you can reconstruct your newlist

```
newlist = []
for entry, values in entries.items():
    sublist = []
    for val in values:
        sublist.append(entries + (val,))
    newlist.append(sublist)
```